# OpenSSL: How to find out number of current SSL Connections?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I need to find the number of current SSL connections for a SSL Context.
Does openssl provide any API to get this number?

Checked the SSL_CTX man page and http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html, couldn't find any reference.

openssl does provide APIs to get the total number of connections: `SSL_CTX_sess_number`, but this returns total number of connections since the beginning. But, what I want is number of 'live' ssl connection currently.

Is there a way to get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find any straight forward way to do this.

I ended up doing this by maintaining a global variable and protect its access by a mutex (since mine was a multi-threaded program)

Every time a new connection is created, increment the count, and decrement it when a connection closes.

Not exact answer but a convenient workaround.